# Broken encapsulation in State pattern in Java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, encapsulation, state-pattern

I have implemented state pattern for my socket library in Java.
I simplified code to reduce size and increase readability just to demonstrate the problem.
I don't know how to encapsulate using of Socket class by states classes.
I've written comments to better understanding the problem.
So, there is an example code:

```
package com.test;

enum ConnectionAttemptResult {
    ConnectionAttemptStarted,
    AlreadyInProgress,
    AlreadyConnected,
    UnableToCreateSocket,
    UnableToConnectSocket,
    UnableToCreateReadEvent
}

class SocketAddress {
    static SocketAddress LocalhostPort(int port) {
        // Code removed.
        return new SocketAddress();
    }
}

class Socket {
    private State currentState;

    Socket() {
        this.currentState = new NotActiveState(this);
    }

    public ConnectionAttemptResult Connect(SocketAddress remoteAddress) {
        return this.currentState.Connect(remoteAddress);
    }

    // Socket class is external and will be used by user.
    // So further methods must be private because they are internal.
    // Calling these methods by a user may broke class functionality.
    // But I can't make them private because then states couldn't access them.
    public void SwitchState(State newState) {
        this.currentState = newState;
    }

    // I removed a lot of code of this class to simplify the code.
    public boolean CreateSocket() {
        // Code removed.
        return true;
    }

    public boolean ConnectSocket(SocketAddress remoteAddress) {
        // Code removed.
        return true;
    }

    public boolean CreateReadEvent() {
        // Code removed.
        return true;
    }
}

abstract class State {
    protected Socket socket;

    State(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public abstract ConnectionAttemptResult Connect(SocketAddress remoteAddress);
}

class NotActiveState extends State {
    NotActiveState(Socket socket) {
        super(socket);
    }

    @Override
    public ConnectionAttemptResult Connect(SocketAddress remoteAddress) {
        if (!socket.CreateSocket())
            return ConnectionAttemptResult.UnableToCreateSocket;

        if (!socket.ConnectSocket(remoteAddress))
            return ConnectionAttemptResult.UnableToConnectSocket;

        if (!socket.CreateReadEvent())
            return ConnectionAttemptResult.UnableToCreateReadEvent;

        socket.SwitchState(new ConnectingState(socket));
        return ConnectionAttemptResult.ConnectionAttemptStarted;
    }
}

class ConnectingState extends State {
    ConnectingState(Socket socket) {
        super(socket);
    }

    @Override
    public ConnectionAttemptResult Connect(SocketAddress remoteAddress) {
        return ConnectionAttemptResult.AlreadyInProgress;
    }
}

class ConnectedState extends State {
    ConnectedState(Socket socket) {
        super(socket);
    }

    @Override
    public ConnectionAttemptResult Connect(SocketAddress remoteAddress) {
        return ConnectionAttemptResult.AlreadyConnected;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        socket.Connect(SocketAddress.LocalhostPort(9898));

        // But I also can call internal methods and break the class functionality, because now they are public.
        socket.CreateSocket();
        socket.CreateReadEvent();
    }
}
```

Where is my mistake?
How usually developers implement this pattern saving encapsulation?
Hope for your help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are many ways to solve this. One is to have the `connect` method return the next `State`. I would also be concerned about the cyclic dependency between `State` and `Socket` since `Socket` is a concrete class. In other words, `Socket` needs an abstraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could make state classes nested private classes and they would have access to internals of the containing class. As we can see the `TransitiveState` can access the `SomethingWithState#previousState` private variable. I think static nested classes could also access the private members of the enclosing class but you'd have to pass them the `SomethingWithState` instance.

The states are an implementation detail so they do not and probably should not be exposed externally.

E.g.

```java
public class StatePatternExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomethingWithState something = new SomethingWithState();
        something.next();
        something.next();
    }
    
    private static class SomethingWithState {
        private State state;
        private State previousState;
        
        SomethingWithState() {
            this.previousState = null;
            this.state = new InitialState();
        }
        
        void next() {
            State next = state.next();
            System.out.println(state.name() + " --> " + next.name());
            previousState = state;
            state = next;
        }
        
        private interface State {
            State next();
            String name();
        }
        
        private class InitialState implements State {
            public State next() {
                
                return new TransitiveState();
            }
            public String name() { return "Initial"; }
        }
        
        private class TransitiveState implements State {
            public State next() {
                System.out.println("Access private previousState from TransitiveState: was " + previousState.name());
                
                return new FinalState();
            }
            public String name() { return "Transitive"; }
        }
        
        private class FinalState implements State {
            public State next() {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Already in final state.");
            }
            public String name() { return "Final"; }
        }
    }
}
```